# load pdf in webview while offline

Tags: android, pdf, webview

How to Embed a PDF into HTML and show it in web view ?
Actually i am trying this but webview not loaded this page.

```
    String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
            String pdfPath = base + "/Principal.pdf";
             Log.e("real path =", ""+pdfPath);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", 
                    "<embed src='"+pdfPath+"' width='500' height='375'>",
                    "application/pdf",
                    "utf-8",
                    "");
```

Comment: @Rohit Goswami did you get any answer?

Comment: Did you get any anwser on this.?

Answer (score 0):

May it will be helpful:

#### For ONLINE:

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

#### For OffLine:

```
try
{
 Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intentUrl.setDataAndType(url, "application/pdf");
 intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 myActivity.startActivity(intentUrl);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
 Toast.makeText(myActivity, "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: for online purpose it is easy to show by using Google docs but i want to show this while offline, means if i don't have any internet connection then i want to show it from sdcard to webView.

Comment: thats why i asked u, where is your pdf? is it online or in your app folder?

Comment: This is saved in my device external storage.

Comment: Updated... check my answer

Comment: Dear I also know this way but my question is for webView,is there any way to show it in webView not in the other screen.