# How to open a pdf file in webview android?

Tags: android

I have generated a pdf using itext library and it gets stored in sdcard. I have to open the pdf in webview , but when I searched for the solution I came to know I can open it using online google doc service ,but my pdf is stored in a sdcard. Is there a way to open a pdf from external storage in a webview?

Comment: No men it's not possible in Android. but you can used some of Third Party Library fro opening pdf within your app.

Comment: Why do you need to open it in a webview? Have you looked here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344

Comment: no webView not embed pdf it supports only html/text but you can read by using default intent.if you want code plz let me know.

Comment: @RohitGoswami I have the code, I was just to know if i can open it in a webview or not.

Comment: I don't think so.i have tried this before but not working at all  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556693/load-pdf-in-webview-while-offline

Comment: @RohitGoswami So how have you managed it?

Comment: Nope but R&D goin on...

Comment: @RohitGoswami will together do R&D and whosoever gets the ans will update it to other...!! :P

Answer (score 3):

To open pdf in Webview , it better to show pdf via google doc service,

```
WebView webView = (WebView) context.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf");
```

this may help you

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this solution because it opens the browser app which isn't really what I want to do if I'm embedding a webview within the app.

Comment: You may need to override the WebViewClient for the WebView in order to make it not open the browser (redirects might be the cause). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18921867/2353588

Comment: Doesn't work, opens browser

Comment: Check my edits and it works

Comment: But It is showing message : no preview available

Answer (score -1):

No, you can`t use WebView to show a PDF file from a sdcard. Only HTML file maybe shown.

The most simple solution of this task is to use an external PDF reader. Such approach it is convenient for users enough because a "hand made" PDF reader you create from a github open source code can
be slow for displaying large pdf files.

```
public class PDFReader {
public void read(Activity context,  String fileName){
    File appFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
        context.getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    File file = new File(appFolder, fileName);

    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "На устройстве не найдено доступного приложения для отображения PDF!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: he want to read pdf in webview not in default launcher.