# Android PDF Reader & Interactive Library

Tags: android, pdf

I been searching everywhere for a nice Android Library to use PDF's with interaction, I only found MuPDF but the library does not match the requirements.

Does anyone know about a nice OpenSorce PDF Reader Library for android that I can also interact with?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23752690/3371708)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Joan's pdfviewer. You can find it  [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)

Comment: Thanks for that one its currently the one Im using but it doesn't let me interact with the PDF file. At the moment I only saw working in iOS with MuPDF Library.

Comment: what do you mean "interact with the PDF file"?

Comment: I know its weird but Im currently developing an Android App that consumes data from a server downloading PDF Files that makes possible to click write and submit forms directly from the PDF File, the only Library I found its MuPDF but is on C and I cant make it compile on Android using NDK as give me error `Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function `, But I have the library compiled ".so" and in jniLibs.

Comment: No I haven't I'll try it now I just compiled MuPDF on the project as a module using version 1.8 > make generate > change to generate a library on that project and on my main project adding the module with compile project (:android)

Answer (score 1):

I will recomend you RadaeePDF.

Its not open source but its "afordable" taking into consideration the time will save you looking and trying for open source projects.

In my experience the performance given by this SDK is great, you may try it for free.

http://www.radaeepdf.com/download/download-android